# Use of never keyword in typescript

Tags: typescript

TS documentation says:

> the **never** type represents the type of values that never occur. Variables also acquire the type **never** when narrowed by any type guards that can never be true.

I didn't understand its usage, can anybody give me an answer with some examples.

Answer (score 56):

1. *"**the never type represents the type of values that never occur.**"*

It might be return type of function that never returns:

```
const reportError = function () {
    throw Error('my error');
}

const loop = function () {
    while(true) {}
}
```

Here, both `reportError` and `loop` type is `() => never`.

2. *"**Variables also acquire the type never when narrowed by any type guards that can never be true**"*

With operators like `typeof`, `instanceof` or `in` we can narrow variable type. We may narrow down the type the way, that we are sure that this variable in some places never occurs.

```
function format(value: string | number) {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return value.trim();
    } else {
        return value.toFixed(2); // we're sure it's number
    }

    // not a string or number
    // "value" can't occur here, so it's type "never"
}
```

3. **Common use case**

Except better type safety (as in cases described above), `never` type has another use case - conditional types. With `never` type we can exclude some undesired types:

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;

type A = NonNullable<boolean>;            // boolean
type B = NonNullable<number | null>;      // number
```

Comment: Can you explain the last case more or provide an example?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts in that example, there's a boolean condition: if `T` does extend the type `null`, then `NonNullable<T>` will evaluate to `never`. And then typescript will raise an error, which is what `NonNullable<T>` is supposed to do.

Comment: Why the `NonNullable<number | null>` returns `number` instead of `never`? To my understanding it seems like the `T extends null | undefined ? never : T` is not run for a `number | null` as a whole but for each part of the union type — `number` is evaluated to `number` and `null` is evaluated to `never` which in turn transforms whole union type into `number | never` hence `number`. Is this behavior documented somewhere (that condition is run for each partial type) and do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @Tooster It's because of "distributive conditional types" : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types

Answer (score 19):

A prior version of the [Typescript documentation for never](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) had multiple examples:

```
// Function returning never must have unreachable end point
function error(message: string): never {
    throw new Error(message);
}

// Inferred return type is never
function fail() {
    return error("Something failed");
}

// Function returning never must have unreachable end point
function infiniteLoop(): never {
    while (true) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

> the `never` type represents the type of values that never occur:

The Typescript compiler assigns types to all your variables/properties. These types can be either the typescript defined types like `number` and `string`, or user defined types made with the `interface` and `type` keyword.

It is useful to think of these types as sets. In other words a type itself is a collection of possible things which your variables/properties can be at that time. For example:

```
// the variable five can be one thing which is a number
const foo = 5; // type = number; 

// bar can be two things
type twoPrimitives = string | number;
let bar: twoPrimitives = 4;
```

- We see foo has a set size of 1 >> {number}
- We see bar has a set size of 2 >> {number, string}

Now with our set definition in mind we can define the `never` type easy:

**the `never` type represents the empty type set >> {}**. i.e. a set with 0 items in it.

For example:

```
// Normally a function which do not have a return value returns undefined implicitly
// However this function throws before ever reaching the end. 
// Therefore the return type will be never
function foo() :never {
   throw new Error("Error");
}

// thisMakesNoSense will be type never, a value can never be number and string at the same time
type thisMakesNoSense = number & string;
```

> Variables also acquire the type never when narrowed by any type guards that can never be true.

TS can check narrow types if they are explicitly checked in if statements. This is called type guards. In other words a type guard is some expression that performs a runtime check that guarantees the type in a certain scope. For example:

```
// The compiler actually screens these if statements and can infer that in the third
// else statement there are no more types left for value to take on and thus the type 
// become never. Another way to think about this is that in the first if statement the
// set of possible types shrinks from string | number to number only.
// Then in the seconds if statement it shrinks from number to never
function typeGuards(
    value: string | number
) {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
        value; // Type string
    } else if (typeof value === "number") {
        value; // Type number
    } else {
        value; // Type never
    }
}
```

Comment: The best explanation of the "never" type so far, thank you.

Comment: This is excellent explanation of the root cause. I had this error when I imported the default useState hook (that actually was never used in the app, thus, never returning), because I was using a typed custom useAppState hook. While the error was confusing, it actually caught the error before executing any code.

Comment: I appreciate this answer since it was illuminating and a different explanation from what is in the docs.

Answer (score 13):

Links that I studied from :
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/never.html
https://egghead.io/lessons/typescript-use-the-never-type-to-avoid-code-with-dead-ends-using-typescript
https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/11/18/typescript-2-0-the-never-type

Can be summarized as the never type is used for cases like :

1. A function never returns (e.g. if the function body has `while(true){}`)

   ```
   //Type () => never

   const sing = function() {
     while (true) {
       console.log("Never gonna give you up");
       console.log("Never gonna let you down");
       console.log("Never gonna run around and desert you");
       console.log("Never gonna make you cry");
       console.log("Never gonna say goodbye");
       console.log("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you");
     }
   };
   ```
2. A function always throws (e.g. in function `foo(){throw new Error('Not Implemented')}`
   the return type of foo is never)

   ```
   // Type (message: string) => never
   const failwith = (message: string) => {
     throw new Error(message);
   };
   ```

Use case: Exhaustive Checks

```
function foo(x: string | number): boolean {
  if (typeof x === "string") {
    return true;
  } else if (typeof x === "number") {
    return false;
  }

  // Without a never type we would error :
  // - Not all code paths return a value (strict null checks)
  // - Or Unreachable code detected
  // But because TypeScript understands that `fail` function returns `never`
  // It can allow you to call it as you might be using it for runtime safety / exhaustive checks.
  return fail("Unexhaustive!");
}

function fail(message: string): never { throw new Error(message); }
```

Comment: Didn't expect to get rick-rolled in a SO answer hahahaha. Thanks for that

Answer (score 5):

`never` is the type with 0 values.

Just as `boolean` is either `true` and `false`, which means there are and only are 2 ways to construct a value of type `boolean`, in TypeScript there are exactly 0 ways to construct a value of type `never`.

But you may ask, "how is `never` any useful then?"

In TypeScript, values are produced by *expressions*. Expressions have types too, which are the same as the type of the values they evaluate to. `parseInt("123")` is type `number` while `[1, 2, 3]` is type `number[]`. But not all expressions can be evaluated to values. Consider:

```
function f() {
  return f()
}
```

An expression `f()` will get you nowhere. `f()` returns `f()` which returns `f()` and on and on and this recursion continues until maximal recursion limit is reached and the program crashes.

So `f()` does not evaluate to any value anyway. But this expression still needs to have a type; which?

The answer is that any type would do. It won't give us a chance to use its return value after all (because it does not have one; also because it will run indefinitely) so we can write

```
function f(): number {
  return f()
}
```

so that `f()` is type `number`; or even write

```
function f<T>(): T {
  return f()
}
```

But usually, we write `never`:

```
function f(): never {
  return f()
}
```

So `never` plays a new role here; it is a type that does not have values, so it marks that the expression is special, that it will cause the program to do something other than produce a value, such as keep running indefinitely.

More often, you will see `never` with code that is sure to throw an error, or cause the program to terminate:

```
function throwSomeError(): never {
  throw new Error()
}

function bye(): never {
  process.exit(0)
}
```

These functions won't return any value either, so we could have chosen any type for their "return type" that actually, does not exist, but we usually use `never` to signify that these functions are very special ones.

Comment: Great breakdown of the concept. Would still like to see a more realistic use-case and how it's actually used in a real JS library or something.

Comment: @CodeFinity I think the two examples in the current TypeScript documentation are fairly realistic.  I've included them as their own answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75367284/1108305

Answer (score 4):

One example is if you throw an error. E.g.

```
function throwError () {
  throw new Error('whoops');
}
```

You can find some more info here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/never.html

Comment: `throw` is a reserved keyword, you can't use it as the name of a function declaration: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token throw`

Answer (score 2):

The TypeScript documentation has changed since you wrote this.  The [new documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#never) provides the following two examples of `never`:

> ```typescript
> function fail(msg: string): never {
>   throw new Error(msg);
> }
> ```

> ```typescript
> function fn(x: string | number) {
>   if (typeof x === "string") {
>     // do something
>   } else if (typeof x === "number") {
>     // do something else
>   } else {
>     x; // has type 'never'!
>   }
> }
> ```

These are examples of the following description of `never` in the new documentation:

> The `never` type represents values which are *never* observed. In a return type, this means that the function throws an exception or terminates execution of the program.
>
> `never` also appears when TypeScript determines there’s nothing left in a union.

Answer (score 0):

If write a custom param decorator in nest js:

```
export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data: never, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    //   what ever we provide arg to the CurrentUser('arg') will be shown as `data`. this decorator does not need any arg
    // never meaans this argument will never be used
    return 'I return the user';
  },
);
```

this is how I use it inside controller:

```
 @Get('/me')
   me(@CurrentUser() user: string) {
      return user;
   }
```

If I pass an argument to CurrentUser() when I used it, that will be shown as 'data' inside the CurrentUser. Since I do not need to pass any arg, I used "never" as "data"s type above.