# Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never' in switch statement

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that describe the data structure from BE, and a class has method for transforming that BE data structure to our FE data structure and vice versa,but during that typescript throw `Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'` error. How do i resolve it, and why it happen ?

```
interface BEStructure {
  a?: string;
  b?: number;
  ...
}

class FEStructure {
  a: string = null;
  b: number = null;
  ...

  static convertToBE(fe: Partial<FEStructure>): BEStructure  {
    const be: BEStructure = {};

    Object.keys(fe).forEach(key => {
      switch (key) {
        case 'a':
        case 'b': 
          // My others logic
          // ERROR HERE
          be[key] = fe[key];
          break;
      default:
          be[key] = fe[key];
      }
    });

    return be;
  }
}
```

I created [a reproduce here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false&declaration=false&ts=3.7.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIFEDKYoFcFi5QoDeAUMsnAPwBcyAzjqAOYDcFyARnciLgFsu0DgF8yZBABs4DBsgBiWHPkLFk5SnHpMorZAF4+uKVI6Uu9fkOiHjpjpyZwwwBMgQB7EADdoYABVPDAAKGAh6AAU4KFc4KQAeJWw8AiIIAD4ASnoMFNV0yk1KD28mbgi0ZVS1FCMSUUcS5AB5LgArCAIAOgBrCABPBjCILO6YTyh0RAALEP6BwwyNTmaGAHdgMAQZ5HnBrJXm5oRZFAByOHPaVePThguua+Rb4+QAenfkAFlFzzAZtB5FJPCw3K9jp9kOgAEowlow5AACVh6AhzWEAG0FgBdOzhbGDHHmN4lLjEOC9EnNAAmEHgJjAN1JZIghIGeKMBNx1JK4maoiyTRKxDUIAqJPEoiAA)

Comment: do you have a field called `never` in DB? What is the type of never?

Comment: @balderman `never` is a TypeScript type. Not yet sure why it's implicitly occurring here though...

Comment: @balderman [Use of never keyword in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42291811)

Comment: @edemaine OK. Thanks. I was not aware of never.

Comment: None of the other [_"...is not assignable to type 'never'"_](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is+not+assignable+to+type+%27never%27%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com) questions helped?

Comment: If you encounter such problems, try to reduce the error to the minimum. Your problem seems to be the same as with [this shortened example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgfgC5kBnMKUAcwG4dkAjI5EAVwFt7paBfLUSWIhQAhTHTjEyFEDTr1irDlyy8sCAPYgyDYqIC8Y3BOQByGOvUmANHOIBGFWs3bj6AxlUB5egCsICMAA6AGsIAE8SAAp6AEpA8ygAUUQAC0jQsOQ9AD5DZGAYZHTwrL0DEzgTZAAfauQM0vL6Exi6IwBtDIBdLIZO8K6VGKA).

Comment: I'm not sure yet why this error occurs, but a simple workaround would be to wrap it into `if (key === 'a') be[key] = fe[key]` and `if (key === 'b') be[key] = fe[key]`

Comment: Is the `BEStructure` the same but optional? Have you tried `Partial<FEStructure >` as a type?

Comment: @crashmstr I also tried that, but I think it not the case

Comment: @Andreas I'm still digging, but none help so far :(

Comment: @A_A thanks ! that workaround would work, but it could have more property in the switch statement

Comment: Checking the other questions is something you should really do before asking the question. It's part of the research phase. See [ask]; the first section is titled "Search, and research..." Note that your definition of `FEStructure` does not match that of `BEStructure` in terms of the types of `a` and `b`. In `FEStructure` they are essentially required, but allow null. In `BEStructure` they are optional and therefore allow undefined, but, if you have `strictNullChecks` enabled, not null.

Comment: The TS error happens because the switch case applies to both a and b at once creating an impossible type condition as it can’t be both string and number.  If you separate the two you won’t have an error.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Surely it's a string OR a number in the body of the case statement? key can't be both a and b simultaneously?  It looks to me like the compiler is just getting confused, not that there's anything fundamentally wrong?

Comment: @Rich N fe[key] is string OR number but be[key] requires string AND number because that’s the only safe way to assign to a property which could require either type.  It’s just a TS error, not an actual runtime problem, so it could be bypassed with an as assertion.  It’s a limitation of the compiler, which doesn’t understand that whichever type be[key] needs is the same type that fe[key] is.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript assignment doesn't seem to be clever enough to do the case analysis itself in this case.  In the statement `be[key] = fe[key]`, the right-hand side gets type `string | number`, while the left-hand side is assignable by type `string & number` which evaluates to `never`, i.e., it can never be assigned.

Here's one solution, which defines an `assign` generic function of the correct type:

```
interface BEStructure {
  a?: string;
  b?: number;
}

function assign<T, Key extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: Key, value: T[Key]): void {
  obj[key] = value;
}

class FEStructure {
  a?: string;
  b?: number;

  static convertToBE(fe: FEStructure): BEStructure  {
    const be: BEStructure = {};

    Object.keys(fe).forEach(key => {
      switch (key) {
        case 'a':
        case 'b': 
          //be[key] = fe[key];
          assign(be, key, fe[key])
          break;
      }
    });

    return be;
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIFEDKYoFcFi5QoDeAUMsnAPwBcyAzjqAOYDcFyARnciLgFsu0DgF8yZGLhAFgAexBUGDYCxAAeACoAaZAGkIAT2QQAHpBAATBsgDWRuTGSaAfAAo5XAFb0ddo-QGhroAbnAANrgQvgDaQQC6AJT0IXLAlsjklJ5eMfaG8cgAvMhhkRBiEgjhcMrIAGJYOPiExJmcNPRMUKwclDz0-EIiEpRMcGDACMgICiHQYJpyGG4w0Q1NeAREEMlomy07lFmUMwpM3OsY2FutKCUkohyclADy3hAEAHT5DKu7Xxgcig6EQAAs3Plii52qdTgwAO7AMAIMHISFGRKwuGnBC1FAAcjgBNoLxxeIYhK4JOQZJxyAA9AzhHkjIUSmtWQU+vTTrUVGo3MJdPldJz8kk6TiuMQ4LYeXDxIrEs84cRWophDzxKIgA)

Answer (score 0):

Please provide reproducable example. I'm unable to reproduce your error.

I think  **@Linda Paiste** is right

I'd willing to bet that this is because of this `be[key] = fe[key];` mutation.

[Official explanation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769)

> When an indexed access T[K] occurs on the source side of a type relationship, it resolves to a union type of the properties selected by T[K], **but when it occurs on the target side of a type relationship, it now resolves to an intersection type** of the properties selected by T[K]. Previously, the target side would resolve to a union type as well, which is unsound.

According to official explanation **`be[key]`** in  `be[key] = fe[key];` resolves to `be['a' & 'b']` which resolves to `be[never]` which in triggers an error:`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'`. Because intersection of `'a' & 'b'` gives `never`

See these answers:

[Assigning properties in an object by iterating through its keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68773327/assigning-properties-in-an-object-by-iterating-through-its-keys/68773501#68773501) ,

[How to selectively assign from one Partial to another in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857960/how-to-selectively-assign-from-one-partial-to-another-in-typescript/67860407#67860407) ,

[Why can I index by string to get a property value but not to set it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834191/why-can-i-index-by-string-to-get-a-property-value-but-not-to-set-it/67836124#67836124) ,

[TypeScript: Why can't I assign a valid field of an object with type { a: "a", b: "b" }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189542/typescript-why-cant-i-assign-a-valid-field-of-an-object-with-type-a-a-b/68190097#68190097)

[My article](https://catchts.com/mutations) dedicated to TS mutations.

Comment: I added a reproduce in my question

Comment: @captain-yossarian If you paste the original code in the question into a text file called index.ts, take out the two sets of '...' (which would have been better commented), and do `tsc index.ts` you get the error.  You must have made a mistake in doing that, I think?

Comment: @RichN I made an update